# NodeJS await/async with nested MySQL query

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I need help about this code:

```
var sqlCheckIfExist = "SELECT my_refer FROM hub_user WHERE my_refer = '" + friendReferCode + "'";
var sqlCodeCheckSameAsMine = "SELECT my_refer FROM hub_user WHERE uid = '" + uid + "'";

async function checkIfUserCodeExist() {
  connection.promise().query(sqlCheckIfExist)
    .then(([rows, fields]) => {
    if (rows == 0) {
      console.log("Non esiste!")
      return res.send(JSON.stringify({
        "status": 500,
        "response": "codeNotExist"
      }));
    }
    checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine()
    console.log("Esiste!")
    console.log(rows[0].my_refer);
  })
    .catch(console.log)
    .then(() => connection.end());
}

async function checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine() {
  connection.promise().query(sqlCodeCheckSameAsMine)
    .then(([rows, fields]) => {
    if (rows == friendReferCode) {
      console.log("Codice uguale!")
      return res.send(JSON.stringify({
        "status": 500,
        "response": "sameCodeAsMine"
      }));
    }
    console.log("Codice non uguale!")
  })
    .catch(console.log)
    .then(() => connection.end());
}

checkIfUserCodeExist()
```

I am establishing the connection in this way:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  global.connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'xx',
    user: 'xx',
    password: 'xx',
    database: 'xx'
  });
  connection.connect();
  next();
});
```

I can't understand one thing:
How can I call nested query? When I check if rows == 0 into checkIfUserCodeExist() function , if its false, I call checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine() but I got this error:

```
Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/usr/myserver/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:135:17)
at Connection.end (/usr/myserver/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:836:26)
at connection.promise.query.then.catch.then (/usr/myserver/addReferFriend.js:45:31)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

How can I fix that thing?

I post the full file here:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var uid = req.body.uid;
    var friendReferCode = req.body.friendReferCode;

    var sqlCheckIfExist = "SELECT my_refer FROM hub_user WHERE my_refer = '" + friendReferCode + "'";
var sqlCodeCheckSameAsMine = "SELECT my_refer FROM hub_user WHERE uid = '" + uid + "'";
async function checkIfUserCodeExist() {
    connection.promise().query(sqlCheckIfExist)
    .then( ([rows,fields]) => {
            if (rows == 0) {
                console.log("Non esiste!")
                return res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500,"response": "codeNotExist"}));
            }
            checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine()
            console.log("Esiste!")
            console.log(rows[0].my_refer);
    })
    .catch(console.log)
    .then( () => connection.end());
    }

    async function checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine() {
        connection.promise().query(sqlCodeCheckSameAsMine)
        .then( ([rows,fields]) => {
                if (rows == friendReferCode) {
                    console.log("Codice uguale!")
                    return res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500,"response": "sameCodeAsMine"}));
                }
                console.log("Codice non uguale!")
        })
        .catch(console.log)
        .then( () => connection.end());
        }

checkIfUserCodeExist()
});

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problems in your program that you have to update.

First of all you must not use a global variable to store a per request database connection. If two requests arrive at the same time then one request would overwrite the `connection` of the other requests created, so you might use the same connection for both requests, and/or you don't close one of the connections which results in a dangling connection, which in the worst case could render your application unresponsive.

To resolve that issue you have to pass the connection with the request object:

```
app.use(async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    if( req.dbConnection ) {
      // ensure that req.dbConnection was not set already by another middleware
      throw new Error('req.dbConnection was already set')
    }

    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'xx',
      user: 'xx',
      password: 'xx',
      database: 'xx'
    });

    res.on("finish", function() {
      // end the connection after the resonponse was send
      req.dbConnection.end()
    });

    // assign a promise base version of connection to request
    req.dbConnection = connection.promise()

    // wait for the connection to be established
    await connection.connect();
    next();
  } catch(err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

To access the per request defined connection you would do something like this:

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
   try {
     await checkIfUserCodeExist(req.dbConnection)

     // so something here after `checkIfUserCodeExist` finished
   }  catch(err) {
     next(err); // if an error occured pass it to the next
   }
})
```

`async` is ment to be used with `await` if you don't have a `await` in your function body then you don't need a `async` before the function.

If you don't have `await` in the function body then you need to return the Promise chain from the function so that the caller can wait for the function to be finished:

```
function checkIfUserCodeExist(connection) {
  return connection.query(sqlCheckIfExist)
    .then(([rows, fields]) => {
      if (rows == 0) {
        console.log("Non esiste!")

        return res.send(JSON.stringify({
          "status": 500,
          "response": "codeNotExist"
        }));
      }
      console.log("Esiste!")
      console.log(rows[0].my_refer);
      return  checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine(connection)
    })
}

function checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine(connection) {
  return connection.query(sqlCodeCheckSameAsMine)
    .then(([rows, fields]) => {
      if (rows == friendReferCode) {
        console.log("Codice uguale!")
        return res.send(JSON.stringify({
          "status": 500,
          "response": "sameCodeAsMine"
        }));
      }
      console.log("Codice non uguale!")
    })
}
```

If you want to go with `async` it would look like this:

```
async function checkIfUserCodeExist(connection) {
  let [rows, fields] = await connection.query(sqlCheckIfExist)

  if (rows == 0) {
    console.log("Non esiste!")
    return res.send(JSON.stringify({
      "status": 500,
      "response": "codeNotExist"
    }));
  }

  await checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine()

  console.log("Esiste!")
  console.log(rows[0].my_refer);
}

async function checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine(connection) {
  let [rows, fields] = await connection.query(sqlCodeCheckSameAsMine)

  if (rows == friendReferCode) {
    console.log("Codice uguale!")
    return res.send(JSON.stringify({
      "status": 500,
      "response": "sameCodeAsMine"
    }));
  }

  console.log("Codice non uguale!")
}
```

You would avoid something like:

```
return res.send(JSON.stringify({
  "status": 500,
  "response": "codeNotExist"
}));
```

Instead of that you would throw a custom error like:

```
throw new CustomError(500, "codeNotExist")
```

And have an error middleware:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  return res.send({
    "status": err.status,
    "response": err.message
  });
})
```

So you have only one place where you create the error response and you can create changes to that error response when ever necessary, e.g. add some additional logging.

**EDIT (to match the updated question)**

```
/* GET users listing. */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var uid = req.body.uid;
  var friendReferCode = req.body.friendReferCode;

  var sqlCheckIfExist = "SELECT my_refer FROM hub_user WHERE my_refer = '" + friendReferCode + "'";
  var sqlCodeCheckSameAsMine = "SELECT my_refer FROM hub_user WHERE uid = '" + uid + "'";

  function checkIfUserCodeExist() {
    return req.dbConnection.query(sqlCheckIfExist)
      .then(([rows, fields]) => {
        if (rows == 0) {
          console.log("Non esiste!")

          return res.send(JSON.stringify({
            "status": 500,
            "response": "codeNotExist"
          }));
        }
        console.log("Esiste!")
        console.log(rows[0].my_refer);
        return checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine(connection)
      })
  }

  function checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine() {
    return req.dbConnection.query(sqlCodeCheckSameAsMine)
      .then(([rows, fields]) => {
        if (rows == friendReferCode) {
          console.log("Codice uguale!")
          return res.send(JSON.stringify({
            "status": 500,
            "response": "sameCodeAsMine"
          }));
        }
        console.log("Codice non uguale!")
      })
  }

  checkIfUserCodeExist()
   .catch(next)
});
```

Comment: have I to put app.use(async function(req, res, next) { in all files that I use the connection?

Comment: @MicheleZotti All middlewares are added to the epxress application before you start it. And for each request the express application checks which of the requested middlewars matches in the order they where attached. So no, you don't put that in all of your files, but you register the middleware for the db connection only **once** and before you register any of your other middlewars that relay on that connection.

Comment: I edited app.use(async function(req, res, next) {
  let connection = mysql.createConnection({
 ... etc into app.js
How can I do in the other js files to call all the function that I posted as main problem?

Comment: @MicheleZotti I updated to code so that it includes a check that `dbConnection` is not set multiple times for the same request.

Comment: @MicheleZotti As I wrote in the answer, the connection is now stored in the `req` as `dbConnection` and cann be access using `req.dbConnection`, and you need to pass it to the function in which you want to use it. Or in case of your nested functions you could replace the `connection.promise()` with `req.dbConnection`

Comment: Yeah but in my file I got router.post('/', function(req, res, next) { etc
Look the main thread, I have updated it with full file

Comment: @MicheleZotti and what exactly is the problem there? Replace `connection.promise()` with `req.dbConnection`. (I updated the answer)

Comment: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined. I got this error :(

Comment: @MicheleZotti Then you didn't register the middleware that creates the connection before those who use the connection.

Comment: Can you tell me what I have to put into app.js?

Comment: @MicheleZotte the `app.use(async function(req, res, next) {... })`  with the code that initializes the connection has to be placed in the `main.js` **before**  you register the router you export by `module.exports = router;`. You really should first learn the basics of how express routing/middlewares work, because understanding that is crucial to be able to correctly work with express. But this is already out of the scope of what you have initially asked in your question.

Comment: Yeah but I don’t understand one thing. Have I to call app.use function into the same file where I putted the two async function?

Comment: @MicheleZotti That's what i meant with you should learn the basic concept of express.  No - as already sayed in my second comment - you don't need to place it in the same file, it is only important in which order those routers/middlewares are registered.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have opened another thread because I have solved this type of problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948375/cannot-read-property-query-of-undefined-mysql-nodejs

Comment: @MicheleZotti It was a careless mistake in the code because I don't know the `mysql2` module well, it should be `req.dbConnection = connection.promise()`. I updated the middleware for creating the connection accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It might be happening because **you terminate your connection** at the end of the **checkIfUserCodeExist** function.
**Remove** the following line and I think it's going to work:

```
connection.end()
```

OR it you want to open and close it every time you can create a method with will return new connection and invoke it before making any DB queries. example:

```
 function getMysqlConnection() {
     const connection = mysql.createConnection({
         host: 'xx',
         user: 'xx',
         password: 'xx',
         database: 'xx'
     });
     connection.connect();
     return connection;
 }

 var sqlCheckIfExist = "SELECT my_refer FROM hub_user WHERE my_refer = '" + friendReferCode + "'";
 var sqlCodeCheckSameAsMine = "SELECT my_refer FROM hub_user WHERE uid = '" + uid + "'";
 async function checkIfUserCodeExist() {
     const connection = getMysqlConnection();
     connection.promise().query(sqlCheckIfExist)
         .then(([rows, fields]) => {
             if (rows == 0) {
                 console.log("Non esiste!")
                 return res.send(JSON.stringify({ "status": 500, "response": "codeNotExist" }));
             }
             checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine()
             console.log("Esiste!")
             console.log(rows[0].my_refer);
         })
         .catch(console.log)
         .then(() => connection.end());
 }

 async function checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine() {
     const connection = getMysqlConnection();
     connection.promise().query(sqlCodeCheckSameAsMine)
         .then(([rows, fields]) => {
             if (rows == friendReferCode) {
                 console.log("Codice uguale!")
                 return res.send(JSON.stringify({ "status": 500, "response": "sameCodeAsMine" }));
             }
             console.log("Codice non uguale!")
         })
         .catch(console.log)
         .then(() => connection.end());
 }

 checkIfUserCodeExist()
```

Comment: and when I have to close the connection?

Comment: when your application is shutting down. 
or if you wanna close it every time, don't forget to open it again before every DB query

Comment: I am doing everytime connection.end because I need only 1 response and stop and not continous connection. Its not closing the connection in my case and its trying to open another one and I got the error that I paste. How can i solve?

Comment: Yes, don't use global at all, it's a bad practice

Comment: Ok and then I create the connection directly into file and not into app.js right?

Comment: Ideally, you need to implement data access layer with a repository for every entity in DB, in this repository you'll create a connection and do all DB query. You can import this repository wherever you need. to insert something into DB you  have to call methods of that repository.

Comment: But you can leave as in the example I provided. if you don't want to overcomplicate things

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are multiple problems with your code. I will start with addressing your specific question and then give some extra tips. :)

You problem lies within this logic:

```
connection.promise().query(sqlCheckIfExist)
    .then(([rows, fields]) => {
    // some code 

    checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine()

   // some code
  })
    .catch(console.log)
    .then(() => connection.end());
```

The `checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine()` function is asynchronous. So, what happens in this chain of code is that you call `checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine()` but you *do not wait for its result* and immediately jump to the last `then()` in which you close the DB connection. So, in essence, the code that is executed in `checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine()` is being executed *after* you close the connection.

You should `return checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine()`. This way you will wait for a `Promise` response from that function.

**Now to my additional points.**

First, `"SELECT my_refer FROM hub_user WHERE uid = '" + uid + "'";` is **BAD**. You expose your application to vulnerabilities like SQL injection. You should escape the dynamic values in the SQL query through some parsing functionality. This is usually done through the ORM (the `connection()` that you use).

Second, if you use `async` functions then use the respective `await` functionality. Like this:

```
async function checkIfUserCodeExist() {
  let rows, fields;

  try {
    [rows, fields] = await connection.promise().query(sqlCheckIfExist);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  if (rows == 0) {
    console.log("Non esiste!");
    return res.send(JSON.stringify({
      "status": 500,
      "response": "codeNotExist"
    }));
  }
  console.log("Esiste!");
  console.log(rows[0].my_refer);

  let result;
  try {
    result = await checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  // do something with "result" if you wish

  await connection.end();
}
```