# Cannot read property 'query' of undefined - MySQL NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I got this type of error when I try to make a post request to my node js server.
I link here the error and the two files so you can understand better what I have done.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at checkIfUserCodeExist (/usr/my_server/addReferFriend.js:13:29)
    [...]
```

I got two files:
app.js and addReferFriend.js

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql= require('mysql2');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

var addReferFriend = require('./addReferFriend');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use(async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    if( req.dbConnection ) {
      // ensure that req.dbConnection was not set already by another middleware
      throw new Error('req.dbConnection was already set')
    }

    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'xx',
        user: 'xx',
        password: 'xx',
        database: 'xx'
    });

    res.on("finish", function() {
      // end the connection after the resonponse was send
      req.dbConnection.end()
    });

    // wait for the connection and assign it to the request
    req.dbConnection = await connection.connect();
    next();
  } catch(err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

app.use('/api/addReferFriend', addReferFriend);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

module.exports = app;
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3955);
```

and addReferFriend.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var uid = req.body.uid;
  var friendReferCode = req.body.friendReferCode;

  var sqlCheckIfExist = "SELECT my_refer FROM hub_user WHERE my_refer = '" + friendReferCode + "'";
  var sqlCodeCheckSameAsMine = "SELECT my_refer FROM hub_user WHERE uid = '" + uid + "'";

  function checkIfUserCodeExist() {
    return req.dbConnection.query(sqlCheckIfExist)
      .then(([rows, fields]) => {
        if (rows == 0) {
          console.log("Non esiste!")

          return res.send(JSON.stringify({
            "status": 500,
            "response": "codeNotExist"
          }));
        }
        console.log("Esiste!")
        console.log(rows[0].my_refer);
        return checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine(connection)
      })
  }

  function checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine() {
    return req.dbConnection.query(sqlCodeCheckSameAsMine)
      .then(([rows, fields]) => {
        if (rows == friendReferCode) {
          console.log("Codice uguale!")
          return res.send(JSON.stringify({
            "status": 500,
            "response": "sameCodeAsMine"
          }));
        }
        console.log("Codice non uguale!")
      })
  }

  checkIfUserCodeExist()
   .catch(next)
});
module.exports = router;
```

I am using Mysql2. Can somebody help me to fix the error?

Thanks in advance,
Michele.

Comment: The `app.use('/api/addReferFriend', addReferFriend);` has to be **after** the `app.use(async function(req, res, next) { ..  let connection = mysql.createConnection( ... })` in the `main.js` because middlewares are executed the order they are registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this package:
- `const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');`

```
`app.use(async function (req, res, next) {
if (req.dbConnection) {
    next();
}
mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'xx',
    user: 'xx',
    password: 'xx',
    database: 'xx'
}).then((conn) => {
    req.dbConnection = conn;
    next();
}).catch((error) => {
    next(error);
});
```

});`

and replace this code:

```
 module.exports = app;
 var server = http.createServer(app);
 server.listen(3955);
```

by this :

```
app.listen(3955, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on port : " + 3955);
});
module.exports = app;
```

You must control addReferFriend.js and remove a catch in end of script

Answer (score 1):

The `app.use('/api/addReferFriend', addReferFriend);` has to be **after** the `app.use(async function(req, res, next) { .. let connection = mysql.createConnection( ... })` in the `main.js` because middlewares are executed the order they are registered.

Comment: Editing in this way I got: Cannot read property 'end' of undefined app.js:45:24 here precisely: req.dbConnection.end()

Answer (score 0):

`connection.connect()` returns void ([check the sources](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/v1.6.4/lib/connection.js#L742)); so `req.dbConnection` is set to undefined.
You have to wait the `connect` event and then bind the connection to `req` and finally call `next`.

---

Otherwise, after a fast reading of `mysql2` documentation, you can simplify with this middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.dbConnection) {
    next();
  }
  else {
    req.dbConnection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'xx',
      user: 'xx',
      password: 'xx',
      database: 'xx'
    });
    next();
  }
})
```

In my opinion you have to create the connection once and not on every request.

Comment: Look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951525/cannot-read-property-end-of-undefined-mysql-nodejs

Comment: how can i do what you said?