# Cannot read property 'end' of undefined - MySQL , NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I want to show you my error with NodeJS and MySQL.
Error is at line 45 of app.js

```
Cannot read property 'end' of undefined
at ServerResponse.<anonymous> (/usr/my_server/app.js:45:24)
```

It happen when I call a request from 'addReferFriend.js' file.
I link here the two files that I am using.

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql= require('mysql2');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

var addReferFriend = require('./addReferFriend');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use(async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    if( req.dbConnection ) {
      // ensure that req.dbConnection was not set already by another middleware
      throw new Error('req.dbConnection was already set')
    }

    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'xx',
        user: 'xx',
        password: 'xx',
        database: 'xx'
    });

    res.on("finish", function() {
      // end the connection after the resonponse was send
      req.dbConnection.end()
    });

    // wait for the connection and assign it to the request
    req.dbConnection = await connection.connect();
    next();
  } catch(err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

app.use('/api/addReferFriend', addReferFriend);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

module.exports = app;
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3955);
```

addReferFriend.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var uid = req.body.uid;
  var friendReferCode = req.body.friendReferCode;

  var sqlCheckIfExist = "SELECT my_refer FROM hub_user WHERE my_refer = '" + friendReferCode + "'";
  var sqlCodeCheckSameAsMine = "SELECT my_refer FROM hub_user WHERE uid = '" + uid + "'";

  function checkIfUserCodeExist() {
    return req.dbConnection.query(sqlCheckIfExist)
      .then(([rows, fields]) => {
        if (rows == 0) {
          console.log("Non esiste!")

          return res.send(JSON.stringify({
            "status": 500,
            "response": "codeNotExist"
          }));
        }
        console.log("Esiste!")
        return checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine(connection)
      })
  }

  function checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine() {
    return req.dbConnection.query(sqlCodeCheckSameAsMine)
      .then(([rows, fields]) => {
        if (rows == friendReferCode) {
          console.log("Codice uguale!")
          return res.send(JSON.stringify({
            "status": 500,
            "response": "sameCodeAsMine"
          }));
        }
        console.log("Codice non uguale!")
      })
  }

  checkIfUserCodeExist()
   .catch(next)
});
module.exports = router;
```

I have no idea how fix this type of problem. It happen when I call the checkIfUserCodeExist() and it doesn't join into the function and it gives directly the error. I can't print any of console.log because it break.

Hope that somebody can help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance for the help,
Michele.

Comment: `return checkIfCodeIsSameAsMine(connection)`, where is `connection` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be `req.dbConnection.end()` the problem... the object `dbConnection` is undefined.

is it possible that the connection is closed first for some reason? so the point to closing connection is not correct?